# Python: how to write a wrapper to make all variables decalared inside a function globals?

Tags: python

I want a function to be run as if it was written in the main program, i.e. all the variables defined therein can be accessed from the main program. I don't know if there's a way to do that, but I thought a wrapper that gives this behaviour would be cool. It's just hacky and I don't know how to start writing it.

Comment: No, there isn't. And this sounds like a bad idea. Global variables should be avoided, particular mutable global state.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga okay, but I have pieces of code written inside functions, and I really want to run them and have all the variables defined therein after run without having to write the lengthy return statements. How can I do that?

Comment: Use the `global` statement in your function. That is the straightforward way. Python, **by design** is discouraging you to do this. Again, this is a *well known antipattern*. Don't do that. Use return, or use a class to encapsulate state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have pieces of code written inside functions, and I really want to run them and have all the variables defined therein after run without having to write the lengthy return statements. How can I do that?

That's what classes are for. Write a class with all your functions as methods, and use instance attributes to store the shared state. Problem solved, no global required.

Comment: How come that I missed this?

Comment: Got a great idea. Once I use classes, if I want to declare all variables therein, just one command `globals().update(my_class.__dict__())`

Comment: I would definitely not consider this as a "great idea".

Answer (score 0):

Define your variables in the global scope and access them inside the function with the global keyword, like so:

```
x=99
def fn():
    global x
    x=100
fn()
print(x) # 100
```

That been said, I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga, this may not be the best way to do it.

Comment: I will be doing that. Although it can be cumbersome to define all the variables in the scope, I might as well just put them in the return statement. It does same time though when calling the function and I don't have to write names to unpack variables returned.

Comment: @AlexDeft really, DONT "do that". Do the RightThing(tm) instead; __use a class__.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I cannot believe that I missed this idea!